# How does the War Caster feat interact with +1 weapons or shields?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, feats, spellcasting

Say I take the War Caster feat, which allows me to use my weapon or shield as a spellcasting focus. If my weapon or shield is a +1, then when I use it was a spellcasting focus, would it act as a +1 wand or rod focus?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If a character can use a +X magic weapon as a spellcasting focus, does it add the bonus to spell attacks or spell save DCs?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/143968/if-a-character-can-use-a-x-magic-weapon-as-a-spellcasting-focus-does-it-add-th)

Comment: @SamLacrumb That question is probably not a duplicate because the War Caster feat doesn't actually make a weapon your spellcasting focus

Answer (score 14):

### If the weapon or shield influenced casting, it would say so

> which allows me to use my weapon or shield as a spellcasting focus

But the feat doesn't do that.  A cleric or paladin may use their shield as a holy symbol, but that's a class specific feature.  A spell casting focus is a separate thing, unless a weapon's description or another feature makes a weapon into a focus. Example: *Ruby of the War Mage* from XGtE

> ... this 1-inch-diameter ruby allows you to use a simple or martial
>   weapon as a spellcasting focus for your spells. For this property to
>   work, you must attach the ruby to the weapon by pressing the ruby
>   against it for at least 10 minutes.

The Warcaster feat doesn't indicate in its text that it changes the character of weapon or shield.  What it *does* do is remove a restriction from the general rule of spell casting: needing a free hand to perform a somatic component of a spell.

> *Prerequisite: The ability to cast at least one spell*
>
> You can perform the somatic components of spells even when you have
>   weapons or a shield in one or both hands.  (PHB, Ch. 6)

What this allows you to do is to cast a spell without doffing the shield or setting down/stowing the weapon.

> Somatic (S)
>   Spellcasting gestures might include a forceful
>   gesticulation or an intricate set of gestures. If a spell requires a
>   somatic component, *the caster must have free use of at least one hand
>   to perform these gestures.*

*That's* the benefit from the Warcaster feat: not having to have a free hand.

#### There are no secret rules

None of the errata nor Sage Advice compendium changed this feat to do other than what is in the description.

#### Weapons with spell casting improvements include them in their text

For example, the Rod of the Pact Keeper

> *Rod, uncommon (+1), rare (+2), or very rare (+3) (requires attunement by a warlock)*
>   While holding this rod, you gain a bonus to spell attack rolls and to
>   the saving throw DCs of your warlock spells. The bonus is determined
>   by the rod’s rarity.

Unless a +1 shield or sword has a similar description, it can't do that.

> Weapon, +1, +2, or +3 Weapon (any), uncommon (+1), rare (+2), or very
>   rare (+3)  > 
>   You have a bonus to attack and damage rolls made with this magic weapon.  The bonus is determined by the weapon’s rarity.

When using the feat, it doesn't say that you *make a spell attack* with the sword, or with the shield, but rather that the shield or sword does not prevent using that hand to perform the somatic components of a spell, which normally requires a free hand.  The hand occupied with shield or sword can be used with the feat; otherwise, the hand must be freed of either shield or sword to perform the somatic components.